# Neighbours in random graphs

Tags: random-graphs

In any random graph on *n* vertices for each pair of vertices *i* and *j*, we include the edge *{i,j}* in the graph with probability 1/2. Show that with high probability every 2 vertices have at least *n*/4 - √*n*log*n* common neighbors.

I do not really know where to start, do we use a Chernoff bound to solve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Given two vertices $i$ and $j$, there are $n-2$ other vertices $k$ that they could possibly have as common neighbors. The probability that any given $k$ is a common neighbor is $\frac14$, so the distribution we're interested in is $\operatorname{Bin}(n-2, \frac14)$.

At that point, yes, a Chernoff bound will finish the job.